# UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported in model.fit()

Tags: python, jupyter, conv-neural-network

Cast string to float is not supported.
Trying to use model.fit() bit throws me an error.
Should have possibly resulted in processing the data batch wise.

code :

```
X_train, X_test , y_train , y_test  = train_test_split(data, labels ,test_size = 0.3, random_state  = 1 )
print(X_train.shape , y_train.shape , X_test.shape , y_test.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size = (5,5), activation= 'relu', input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size = (5,5), activation= 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate= 0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3) , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5)  )
model.add(Dense(43, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

epochs = 15 
Net = model.fit(X_train , y_train , batch_size = 32 , epochs = epochs , validation_data = (X_test , y_test))
```

error :

```
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

   1 epochs = 15
   ----> 2 Net = model.fit(X_train , y_train , batch_size = 32 , epochs = epochs , validation_data = (X_test , y_test))

UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
 [[node categorical_crossentropy/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-15-59f0001da0f5>:2) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1398]

Function call stack: train_function
```

Comment: What do the data look like?

Comment: From that I understand you're asking the form of data, that would be Images.

Comment: What's `X_train.dtype, y_train.dtype`?

Comment: X_train  --> float64
y_train -->  <U7

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `<U7` - it's a string, not a number. You should somehow encode strings into numbers, maybe with [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)

Comment: I'll try that...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the labels.

```
with open("/input/train.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    for item in reader:
        training_sentences.append(item[3])
        training_labels.append(item[4])
```

This piece of code returned the `training_labels` as

```
['1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 ...]
```

When I compiled the model. I faced the same issue.

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
```

Here is how I solved it.

```
with open("/input/train.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    for item in reader:
        training_sentences.append(item[3])
        this_label = item[4]
        if this_label == '0':
            training_labels.append(0)
        else: 
            training_labels.append(1)
```